# Can I write a file name containing path separators in Linux?

Tags: python, linux, path, escaping

I've got a python program that gets fired off by Nagios check failures and calls out an engineer. As part of this it saves state files using the name of the service that's failed as part of the file name. This is fine, except that some of the services contain slashes (eg. for checks on whether an NFS mount point is present, the service is just named after the mount point) and when python tries to create files with this name, it interprets the name as a directory tree (where some parts of the tree don't exist) and fails.

Obviously there are ways around this (eg. I can stop using the service name in the file path), but I quite like it the way it's designed at present because I can tell if a state file exists already for a given service without needing to read every state file in the directory. Is there any way I can write a file name containing path separators?

What I'm after is something like:

```
service_name = '/data/servername'
filename = escape_service_name(service_name)
statepath = os.join(state_dir, filename)
statefile = open(statepath, "w")
# Write state file details here
```

...but I can't see how to escape the slashes so this works.

Comment: You want the actual file name to contain the path separators? If so, I don't see how what would be possible if the OS is using those exact same symbols to break up a path into directories and filenames. Otherwise, if I'm misunderstanding, have you tried using raw strings? e.g., something along the lines of `r'/data/servername'`

Comment: Yeah, or some escape sequence that'll work. I didn't know if Linux might allow it with appropriate escaping. Dragonroot's answer should work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a filename with path separators directly. I used percent encoding in those situations:

```
import urllib

# outputs "foo%2Fbar"
print urllib.quote('foo/bar', '')
```

The nice thing about such solution is that percent encoding is completely reversible, so you can reconstruct your filename back perfectly. If you merely replace `/` with something like `_`, you won't be able to know whether the original char was `/` or `_`. With percent encoding, you can, since it would escape the `%` sign too.

Comment: Yeah, hadn't thought of that, I think I'll try this way. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can "escape" slashes by replacing them with some other symbol (i.e. _). Of course, some collisions can appear. But I guess there exists symbol allowed in filenames but not occuring in service names.

More complicated solution: you can encode service names using something like [base32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32).

Comment: Yeah, I thought about just replacing the slashes in the name, but then I have some other character (or set of characters) that can't appear in the service name, and if there's some other character that gives similar problems that I haven't thought of, I have the same problem again later. Still the most likely solution if there isn't a way to do this.

Base32 doesn't help because I need to encode the slashes (and any other special characters present) as well.

Comment: You are not right: base32 allows you to quote any sequence of bytes. As the result you will get a sequence of letters and digits (and =, but it can be omitted). And it also is completely reversible.